# Using cfenv as error control in C++, problem with using pow as sqrt

Tags: c++, error-handling, cmath

I've started using cfenv for checking overflow and underflow on variables and I've seen that you can also check other things like division by zero and "invalid".

The example that it gives by invalid operation it's square root of -1, and it works:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::feclearexcept(FE_INVALID);

    double invalid_var = 0;

    std::cout << "Invalid flag before: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID) << std::endl;

    invalid_var = sqrt(-1);

    std::cout << "Invalid flag after: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Invalid flag before: 0
> Invalid flag after: 1

The problem is that in my code I don't use sqrt as square roots, I use the mathematical equivalent x^(1/2). Using pow instead of sqrt it gives as a result 1, and no flag:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::feclearexcept(FE_INVALID);

    double invalid_var = 0;

    std::cout << "Invalid flag before: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID) << std::endl;

    invalid_var = pow(-1, 1/2);

    std::cout << "Invalid flag after: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Invalid flag before: 0
> Invalid flag after: 0

Is there something I can do? I'm new on C++ and I don't know the kind of math functions and exceptions you use, maybe I'm giving it the wrong approach.

Comment: `1/2` is integer math, and is 0. You want either `0.5` or `1.0 / 2.0`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm lol rookie mistake... Python has really affected me xD